# Rails search serialized records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the model I serialize the column category in Event model to be array, so i have

```
serialize :category
```

The thing is, i need to provide search function to users. So how do i search if a category is inside an event.

```
Event.find(:all, :conditions => ['category = ?', params[:category]])
```

This won't work as the category is stored as serialized array. Any idea?

The only way i can think of get all the events and filter out each instance.

```
Event.all.select{|e| e.category.include? params[:category]}
```

This is not efficient at all.

Or else, i can use like statement

```
Event.find(:all, :conditions => ['category = ?', "%-#{params[:category]}%"])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a separate table and model for categories. Then you can get all events in a category by using a has_many association.

Comment: However, the category would only have 3 or 4 entries. So i think maybe not necessary to create extra table for it. Let's say create table is not an option. Is there a better way for search?

Comment: I think it is more efficient to create a table. An SQL integer is only 4 bytes but a varchar(255) is 256 bytes. So, references between an event, through a 4 rows in a categories_events table, to a categories table will be 4 rows * 2 references * 4 bytes = 32 bytes. Also, doing an integer compare is much quicker than a string compare.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.to_yaml` to match the serialize format stored in the DB.

```
Event.where(category: params[:category].to_yaml)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Event.where("category IN (?)" , params[:category].to_yaml)
```